# Hack altering pages pages at server

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, iis-7

It looks like my site has been hacked. I have removed all files form the site (on IIS7) and replaced it with a simple asp file:

```
<%@ Language=VBscript%>

<%

%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
</head><body>
</body>
</HTML>
```

If the page is called with the HTTPreferer as 'googlebot' a load of spam links are inserted just before the body close tag. Otherwise the page works fine.

I have the site on shared hosing but have access to IIS7 manager for the site with limited control. I cannot see a URL rewrite function or anything that will allow the page to be altered before the data being sent. There are some functions of the IIS7 system I dont have access to as it is a shared server and I am trying to work with my hosting provider to resove the problem, but they also seem to be drawing a blank.

any ideas? its killing my google rankings!

PS is does affect another of my sites on the same hosing system but not all my sites nor a couple of others I tested.

Comment: Have you check your global.asa file?   What happens if you also take out the VBScript tags?

Comment: If you have removed ALL files then surely it must be a hosting issue.

Comment: No Global.asa, if I remove VB script tags still inserts. Only doent insert if I change name to bob.html - seems independednt of content of file. I agree it seems to be a hosting issue, but I am struggleing to fine out where. There doesnt appear to be anything that would allow this sort of change active on the IIS7 manager.

Comment: [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place for this kind of question.

Comment: You will have to check the configuration Handler Mapping in IIS for *.asp, it should point too %windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll   You will also want to check to see if asp.dll has been infected/changed.